# Find the Peaks of contour in Python-OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have got a binary image/contour containing four human beings, and I want to detect/count all humans. Since there are occlusions, so I think it is best to get the head/maxima in the contour of all the humans. In that case human can be counted. 
I am able to get the `global maxima\topmost point` (in terms of calculus language), but I want to get all the `local maximas`

The code for finding the topmost point is as suggested by Adrian in his blogpost i.e.:

> topmost = tuple(biggest_contour[biggest_contour[:,:,1].argmin()][0])

Can anyone please suggest how to get all the `local maximas`, instead of just topmost location?
Here is the sample of my Image:

[image]

Comment: What if someone raises a hand?

Comment: That is the simplest case I want to solve. I will train classifier , but currently needs an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "local maximum" can be tricky to pin down, but if you start with a simple method you'll develop an intuition to look further. Even if there are methods available on the web to do this work for you, it's worth implementing a few basic techniques yourself before you go googling.

One simple method I've used in the path goes something like this:

1. Find the contours as arrays/lists/containers of (x,y) coordinates.
2. At each element N (a pixel) in the list, get the pixels at N - D and N + D; that is the pixels D ahead of the current pixel and D behind the current pixel
3. Calculate the point-to-point distance
4. Calculate the distance along the contour from N-D to N+D
5. Calculate (distanceAlongContour)/(point-to-point distance)
6. ...

There are numerous other ways to do this, but this is quick to implement from scratch, and I think a reasonable starting point: Compare the "geodesic" distance and the Euclidean distance.

A few other possibilities:

- Do a bunch of curve fits to chunks of pixels from the contour. (Lots of details to investigate here.)
- Use Ramer-Puecker-Douglas to render the outlines as polygons, then choose parameters to ensure those polygons are appropriately simplified. (Second time I've mentioned R-P-D today; it's handy.) Check for vertices with angles that deviate much from 180 degrees.
- Try a corner detector. Crude, but easy to implement.
- Implement an edge follower that moves from one pixel to the next in the contour list, and calculate some kind of "inertia" as the pixel shifts direction. This wouldn't be useful on a pixel-by-pixel basis, but you could compare, say, pixels N-1,N,N+1 to pixels N+1,N+2,N+3. Or just calculate the angle between them.